R Programming functions understanding
I am new to R programming. I am going through some R programs written by ex-colleague. However, I am not able to understand below two functions. Can you please help me in understanding these two functions line by line, what exactly they do?
cmdargs <-function(arguments){

    Cmdnames <- c() 
    Cmdvalues <- c()

    for(i in 1:length(arguments)){
        Cmdnames[length(Cmdnames)+1] <- strsplit(arguments[i],'=')[[1]][1]
        Cmdvalues[length(Cmdvalues)+1] <- strsplit(arguments[i],'=')[[1]][2]
        names(Cmdvalues) <- Cmdnames
    }
    return(Cmdvalues)
}




find <- function(Cmdvalues,arg,default)
{
     if(is.na(Cmdvalues[arg]))
          return(default)
     else{
          return(unname(Cmdvalues[arg]))
     }
 } 


What you should do is learn to read the man pages, e.g.  type  ?strsplit .   Grab one of the many introductory tutorials available online and learn the basics of R

The first function takes a (presumably) character vector called arguments, takes each of them (the for loop) and splits them into two parts, separated by an = sign, one called Cmdnames and the other Cmdvalues (the two strsplit commands).  It then uses the Cmdnames as the names for the Cmdvalues vector, and finally returns the latter.
The second function takes a Cmdvalues vector, as produced by the first function, tries to find the (Cmd)value with (Cmd)name arg, and returns it.  If the Cmdvalues vector doesn't have a value with that name, the value specified by the function's default argument is returned.
As a side note, the first function is poor R code, and has several efficiency problems.  For instance, there is no point in splitting the string twice just to get both parts, and the recursive concatenation is also a bad idea, as is the for loop.  Don't learn too much from it...

Thanks a lot,Ze Loff..! This would be really helpful.

Following @ZéLoff' observation..

the first function is poor R code, and has several efficiency problems.

..here's a better alternative (toy data at the end):
For cmdargs:
library(tidyverse) 

# ----------------
new_cmdargs <- \(x) x %>% 
  as_tibble_col() %>% 
  separate(value, c("name", "value"), "=") %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  as_vector()

# The output -----
> new_cmdargs(aux)
Luke Skywalker           C-3PO           R2-D2     Darth Vader     Leia Organa  
       " Human"        " Droid"        " Droid"        " Human"        " Human"

For find, just use purrr::pluck:
Obs. find is a r-base function (see ?find). Avoid using it as a name for your own functions.
aux <- new_cmdargs(aux)

> purrr::pluck(aux, "Darth Vader", .default = "Nops")
[1] "Human"

> purrr::pluck(aux, "Darth Maul", .default = "Nops")
[1] "Nops"



Toy data
# Toy data ------- 
# aux <- starwars %>% slice_head(n = 5) %$% paste0(name, "=", species)

aux <- c(
  "Luke Skywalker=Human", 
  "C-3PO=Droid", 
  "R2-D2=Droid", 
  "Darth Vader=Human", 
  "Leia Organa=Human")


Or using base R only: splt <- strsplit(aux, "="); values <- sapply(splt, "[", 2); names(values) <- sapply(splt, "[", 1)
